# Speakers and headphones play no sound on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: 14.04, sound, toshiba

I just bought a second hand Toshiba Satellite S50-D and installed Ubuntu 14.04. Everything seems to be in working order, except my sound does not work. The speakers seem to be recognised in the sound menu, and when I took a look at pavucontrol it shows the audio being streamed to the device (that is, the sound bars move when I play music or something), yet neither the speakers nor the headphone jack play any sound. Before you suggest it, the devices are selected for output, and they are not muted.

Any suggestions? Some sources seem to say it requires messing about with probemasks but I don't know if that's relevant to my issue or how to go about it if it is.HDMI audio works fine, and the system panel accurately detects whether or not headphones are plugged in.

I really, really don't want to have to put Win8 back on this thing, but this is kind of a deal breaker. I'd really appreciate some guru assistance.

EDIT: ALSAMIXER detects the card as "HD-Audio Generic" with chip "IDT 92HD99BXX" if that's helpful in any way.

Comment: can you copy in your question this command result: `aplay -l `  . Also note that in many cases , alsamixer shows the main device only when pressing F6 function key and selecting 2nd device

Comment: aplay -l returns:

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: 92HD99BXX Analog [92HD99BXX Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I already figured the F6 bit in alsamixer, and on a more interesting note, I've fixed a part of the issue by reinstalling with the bios set to CSM mode instead of UEFI. Bizarre, but I'll take it. The sound works when I start the machine, but returns to the previous state after waking from suspend.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar sound card experience on an old toshiba satallite pro m30.
Not a very technical answer this, but my problem turned out to be the "hidden" volume control situated under the front edge of the laptop just below the main input light.
This seems to to get rotated to the "off" position quite easily. I spent hours trying to sort this problem - Doh!

Answer (score -1):

on my toshiba tecra m5 i did not have any sound,i found that the 
solution was to go in to bios and change the setting in configuration
device config=setup by os,change to device config=all devices.
that solved it for me,i am running ubuntu 14.10.
i hope this solution might be helpfull for others too.